# Ошибка при использовании curl

Tags: php, json, curl

Я новичок в php, поэтому не судите строго.

Имеется функция createOrEditUser();
Помимо нее есть функции, которые построены по тому же запросу, но не POST, а GET. 
Функции вызываю из другого файла с помощью echo;
Все работает, выводит как надо. Но когда в этой функции делаю POST запрос, то происходит ошибка. Все ключи для использования API правильные, все работает нормально(на основе рабочей ф-ции написал). 
Ошибку даже не выводит, просто мой файл test.php с echo перестает даже выдавать результат выполнения других функций и просто белый экран.

> Вот код:

```
public function createOrEditUser()
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::url.'customers/create_or_update?access_token='.self::GetToken()'&organization='.self::GetOrgList());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"customer":{"phone":"+79274728106","name":"Тест"}}');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'));
    $out = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $out;
}
```

URL правильный. JSON валидный.

Comment: `self::GetToken()'&organization='` -- опечатка, пропущена конкатенация (точка)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае ошибки `curl_exec` вернёт `false`. Узнать что пошло не так, поможет `curl_error`. Кроме того, тело ответа может быть пустым (это же POST запрос).

Вообще лучше один раз написать универсальную функцию запроса (или использовать [готовую](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle))

```
function request($method, $url, array $headers, $body = '', $opts = []) {
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $opts + [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  => $body,
    ]);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    if ($result === false) {
        $error = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        throw new \Exception($error);
    }

    $headerSize = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $responseHeaders = substr($result, 0, $headerSize);
    $headers = array_filter(explode("\r\n", $responseHeaders));
    $responseBody = substr($result, $headerSize);
    $code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $response = [
        0 => $code,
        'code' => $code,
        1 => $headers,
        'headers' => $headers,
        2 => $responseBody,
        'body' => $responseBody,
    ];
    curl_close($curl);

    return $response;
}

try {
    list($code, $headers, $body)= request(
        'POST',
        self::url . 'customers/create_or_update?access_token=' . self::GetToken() . '&organization=' . self::GetOrgList(),
        ['Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'],
        '{"customer":{"phone":"+79274728106","name":"Тест"}}'
    );
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'FAIL: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

if ($code === 200) {
    echo 'OK';
} else {
    echo 'FAIL: ' . $code;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Добавил curl_error, но все равно выводит пустоту :(

Comment: @vupseen а ошибки включены? Если нет, то включите (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). Попробуйте изолировать проблему. Посмотрите какой код ответа возвращается.